# Pass Value between UIView controller & UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, unrecognized-selector

I'm new to iOS and its developing. I'm developing iPhone application.there i have UITableView and UIWebView. When i am pressing UITableview's cell, according to click there i want to load various webpages in my UIWebView. for that  i have to pass string link to DeatailViewController from EssentialViewController.there im getting Errors.please help me.

Error Log

```
2014-07-07 07:09:53.511 WADTourisum[564:60b] -[UINavigationController currentActiveNVC]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e9b650
2014-07-07 07:09:53.514 WADTourisum[564:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController currentActiveNVC]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e9b650'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01a421e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0158f8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01adf243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a3250b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01a320ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   WADTourisum                         0x00002c9b -[AMSlideMenuContentSegue perform] + 171
    6   UIKit                               0x007b3f0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
    7   UIKit                               0x0037041c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 72
    8   WADTourisum                         0x00013b03 -[Essentialinfocontroller tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 179
    9   UIKit                               0x003399a1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
    10  UIKit                               0x00339b14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    11  UIKit                               0x0033e10e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    12  UIKit                               0x0026d0aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    13  UIKit                               0x0026d055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    14  UIKit                               0x0026ce76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01a0a36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01a0a2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x019e8254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x019e79d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x019e77eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03a365ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03a3642b GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x0024ff9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  WADTourisum                         0x000046fd main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02089701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EssetialViewController.h

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface Essentialinfocontroller : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *info;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary * courses;
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSArray *coursekeys;

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet DetailViewController * myWebview;

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* customeLink;

@end
```

EssetialViewController.m

```
#import "Essentialinfocontroller.h"
@interface Essentialinfocontroller ()
@end
@implementation Essentialinfocontroller
@synthesize myWebview;
@synthesize courses;//dictionary type object
@synthesize coursekeys; //array type object
@synthesize customeLink;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *myfile= [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"essentialinfo" ofType:@"plist"];

   // NSLog(@"testing path %@",myfile);

    courses=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myfile];

    coursekeys =[courses allKeys];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [courses count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell * cell=[[ UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    NSString * currentCourseName =[coursekeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel]setText:currentCourseName];

    cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return  cell;
}

//implement stack method

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




    if(indexPath.row==0){

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];//**Error is here**


        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"story"];

        customeLink=@"https://www.facebook.com/";



        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];


    }
    if (indexPath.row==1) {
        NSLog(@"myUrl-->2 ");

    }



}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"])
    {

        DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        vc.link=customeLink;
    }
}

//end

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *info;

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * link;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,weak)NSString *customelink;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize info;

@synthesize link;

@synthesize customelink;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.customelink=self.link;


    NSLog(@"link--> %@",self.customelink);

    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:customelink];
    NSURLRequest * requestURL= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [info loadRequest:requestURL];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

[image: My Segue image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

**prepareForSegue**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"])
    {
        DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.link=@"https://www.facebook.com/";
    }
}
```